# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 create quote product records with Workflow

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have created a dialog that creates a quote in CRM 2011 Online and now I am trying to have a child process start another dialog to fill that quote with quote products. Sadly quote products does not initially appear in the drop down of entities that can be created within a workflow/dialog.

Does anyone know how to create a quote product from a dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Dialogs & Workflows cannot create Quote Products (nor invoice/order/opportunity products). This has been the case since the early days and is still the case with CRM 2011.

I've been told it's due to the heavy logic that is triggered upon save of these records (rolling up totals to the parent record etc) however I struggle to see why this prevents workflows from automatically creating this data. It's something that I hope is fixed in the next major version of CRM.

As an alternative, if you use a tool like Scribe to import the data (assuming you calculate the header fields yourself) everything works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

We have created a solution with a workflow that creates order products, opportunity, quote and invoice products as well.

http://www.cartagena.no/#!mscrm-addons/l2y55

Andreas, Cartagena

Answer (score 2):

To address this limitation in CRM we have built a custom workflow step that enables you to create quote products, as well as opportunity products, orders products and invoice products. The workflow step is very easy to install, just import the managed solution and you're ready to create your dialogs and workflows. You can download the solution from [our web site](http://www.cartagena.no/SitePages/Articles.aspx?artid=47&CatId=3). There you'll also find all the documentation you need. To get a free demo license (valid for a month), send us an email.